# Suggestions for practice problems

Tags: homework

As a first year student at IITM, we have a beginner course on Mathematica. For the end-semester examinations we need practice questions due to insufficiency of problems at hand, and I was wondering if anyone knew any resource that could help us out? Our level is that of an introductory one, having done assignments on a range of topics like Numerical Integration, Monte Carlo methods, Regression, Device and Camera control, Signals and Systems, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.